# Two patches in one figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

please I'm trying to make two patches in one figure, after plotting the first one  it disappears and I get the second one 'disk2' only. I've tried 'hold on' but it doesn't work
basically I've this piece of code for plotting

```
for ii=1:length(y)

set(disk1, 'xdata', xcirc1(:,ii), 'ydata', ycirc1(:,ii), 'zdata', zcirc1(:,ii));

set(disk2, 'xdata', xcirc2(:,ii), 'ydata', ycirc2(:,ii), 'zdata', zcirc2(:,ii));

 drawnow

  pause(0.01)

end
```

And this is how the `disk`'s are created

```
disk1= patch('xdata', xcirc1(:,1), 'ydata', ycirc1(:,1), 'zdata', zcirc1(:,1)); 
disk2= patch('xdata', xcirc2(:,1), 'ydata', ycirc2(:,1), 'zdata', zcirc2(:,1));
```

Any one could please give me suggestion for solving it.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you make a small complete sample code so we can run it?

Comment: Hi Yvon,
Unfortunately the code is pretty long to be posted here, basically  after sitting the patch for the disks as following :

disk1= patch('xdata', xcirc1(:,1), 'ydata', ycirc1(:,1), 'zdata', zcirc1(:,1));
disk2= patch('xdata', xcirc2(:,1), 'ydata', ycirc2(:,1), 'zdata', zcirc2(:,1));
 I use the code "in the main post" for plotting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hold` does the job for me.

```
xcirc1 = rand(3,5);
xcirc2 = rand(3,5);
ycirc1 = rand(3,5);
ycirc2 = rand(3,5);
zcirc1 = rand(3,5);
zcirc2 = rand(3,5);

hfig = figure;
hax = axes('Parent',hfig);
hold(hax,'on')
disk1= patch('xdata', xcirc1(:,1), 'ydata', ycirc1(:,1), 'zdata', zcirc1(:,1)); 
disk2= patch('xdata', xcirc2(:,1), 'ydata', ycirc2(:,1), 'zdata', zcirc2(:,1));
for ii=1:5
    set(disk1, 'xdata', xcirc1(:,ii), 'ydata', ycirc1(:,ii), 'zdata', zcirc1(:,ii));
    set(disk2, 'xdata', xcirc2(:,ii), 'ydata', ycirc2(:,ii), 'zdata', zcirc2(:,ii));
    pause(0.01)
end
hold(hax,'off')
```